# Does MySQL handle queries within a procedure synchronously?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Perhaps the title is a little misleading, so I'll explain my question in further detail. Obviously the queries inside of the procedure are executed synchronously and in order, but are procedures themselves executed synchronously?

Lets say I have a procedure called "Register" which handles a couple of queries, for example it looks like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE account_inserted INT(11);
    INSERT INTO accounts (...) VALUES (...);
    SET account_inserted = LAST_INSERTED_ID(); # <------
    QUERY using account_inserted...
    QUERY using account_inserted...
    QUERY using account_inserted... 
    ...
END
```

Now lets say that there were numerous requests to register coming in at the same time (For example purposes let us say around 200-300 requests) would it execute all of the procedures in order? Or is it possible would the `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` variable to conflict with a row inserted from another procedure that is being executed in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're muddling three things:

1. > Whether MySQL executes procedures synchronously

   This could be interpreted to mean either "*does MySQL wait for each command within a procedure to complete before moving on to the next?*" or "*does MySQL wait for the entire procedure to complete before accepting further instructions from the connection that invoked the `CALL` command?*".  In both cases, the answer is "yes, it does".
2. > Whether invocations of MySQL procedures are executed **atomically**

   As with any other series of commands, commands within procedures are only atomic if performed within a transaction on tables that use a transactional storage engine.  Thus a *different connection* may well execute another `INSERT` between the `INSERT` in your procedure and the command that follows.
3. > Whether `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` is guaranteed to return the value generated by the immediately preceding `INSERT` command in the procedure?

   Yes, it is.  The most recent insertion ID is maintained on a *per-connection* basis, and as described above the **connection** waits for `CALL` to complete before further commands are accepted.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it answered the question and concern I had posted on miken's response.

Answer (score 3):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a ***per-connection basis***. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column ***by that client***. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: The reason this is confusing me is because I am using stored procedures in PhpMyAdmin, which by default did not have a keep-alive connection. I had to enable the keep-alive functionality in the configuration files in order for LAST_INSERT_ID to work properly, so I was wondering if PhpMyAdmin would in anyway conflict with this functionality, as the queries are all being called from a stored procedure there.

Comment: The procedure calls, if they're coming from the same client, should be executed synchronously. Edit: I see eggyal has a more in-depth answer up above, so I can just say "what he said."